# LWJGL 3 - problem with flickering when rendering terrain with colors

Tags: opengl, java, terrain, lwjgl3

For while now I m trying to built a terrain generator for my game engine and again I'm stuck with problem.

I'm trying to generate a terrain using colors, so no textures. In short my problem is flickering. Hope this pictures will describe better my problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The way I'm generating this is using shared vertices. If I'm generating 2*2 terraing, I'm actually only creating 9 points.
Something like this.

[image]

For color , I made that every second point will get slightly darker green.

When I add height generation, there is no flickering.

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
It probably got something to do with using shared points. I now tried using all unique points for each square and no flickering.

[image]

EDIT:
I found was the cause. I was generating indices wrong way.

```
    public void generateSharedIndices(int rowVertices,int columnVertices){
    for(int row = 0; row < rowVertices - 1 ; ++row){
        for(int column = 0; column < columnVertices -1 ; ++column){
            int leftDownPoint = ((row * columnVertices) + column);
            int rightDownPoint = leftDownPoint + 1;
            int rightUpPoint = rightDownPoint + columnVertices;
            int leftUpPoint = rightUpPoint - 1;

            addNewValueToCurrentPointer(leftDownPoint);
            addNewValueToCurrentPointer(rightDownPoint);
            addNewValueToCurrentPointer(rightUpPoint);
            addNewValueToCurrentPointer(rightUpPoint);
            addNewValueToCurrentPointer(leftUpPoint);
            addNewValueToCurrentPointer(leftDownPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

In the end indices should look like this
( 0  1  5  5  4  0  )
( 1  2  6  6  5  1  )
( 2  3  7  7  6  2  )
( 4  5  9  9  8  4  )
but I made mistake and it was generating them wrong.

Comment: You need to show us some code, so we can at least guess where you went wrong

Comment: Thank you I thought problem was somewhere in some opengl flag that I forgot to turn on or off, but  the moment I saw this comment I knew I made some mistake in my code for generating terrain.